# Display product attributes with image in single product page

Tags: woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

Could you help me a little?
I used this snippet, is working well.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_dimensions', 45 );
function product_attribute_dimensions(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_dimensions';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

    if ( $value ) {
        $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;

        echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602770/17244939

But I can't figure, how I can display the attribute attached image and not the text. Could you help me?

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801999/display-custom-taxonomy-term-images-for-woocommerce-product-attributes

Comment: By default attributes dont have image so if you use a plugin or another piece of code for that you need to debug your term to find what data holds and then grab it.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $product;

$ingredients = $product->get_attributes( 'color' );

foreach( $ingredients as $attr_name => $attr ){
    foreach( $attr->get_terms() as $term ){
        if ( wc_attribute_label( $attr_name ) == "Color" ) {
            echo $term->name ;
            $meta_image = get_wp_term_image($term->term_id);
            echo '<img src="'.$meta_image.'"/>';
        } 
        else echo '';
    }
}
```

**Can you try with above Code and color replace with your attribute**

Comment: Sorry, its not working. Fatal error. But thanks your time!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to display a small custom "brand" attribute image before the product title so I used a woocommerce hook on the single product page. WC prefixes the the attribute name with "pa_". Different size images are available such as "medium", "thumbnail", "woocommerce_thumbnail", "woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail" etc etc. I also wanted to make the image smaller keeping it left justified so I used a style tag with transform and webkit-transform css.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_resize_images', static function() { return false; }); // Stop warning when WC attempts to resize svg's 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );                                 
function add_custom_text_after_product_title(){                                                                                
 global $product;                                                                                                              
 $product_brands = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_brand' );                                                        
 $term_image = get_term_meta($product_brands[0]->term_id, 'term_image', true);                                                 
 $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $term_image,'woocommerce_thumbnail');                                        
 if(isset($image_attributes[0])) {                                                                                             
  echo "<img src='{$image_attributes[0]}' style='-webkit-transform-origin-x:0;transform:scale(0.5);'>";                 
 }                                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                              
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_text_after_product_title', 5);
```